# Date format into Excel

Tags: excel, ui-automation, abap, dynpro

I am trying to use BATCH Input for my record adding page.

But I can't receive the date format from Excel; it is always shown as '00000000'.

I tried those examples : 31.07.2012 20123007 20120730 and so on..

But those are not solve my problem. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you convert from Excel's date format to internal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format can be indicated when you create a Batch Input session from SHDB, or from **BDC_OPEN_GROUP** function module **DATFM** parameter. If the DATFM parameter value is "%" (default), SAP will use the user's date format.

1.You can use the code to convert a date variable from internal to external format

```
DATA table_date_field TYPE d. "internal format YYYYMMDD, 8 digits
DATA screen_date_field TYPE bapi_date. "external format 10 characters
table_date_field = '20101231'.
WRITE table_date_field TO screen_date_field.
```

2. You can get the appropriate date format by calling the function module
   '**DATUMSAUFBEREITUNG**'.